# NSTableView double-clicking/renaming

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

By default, double-clicking triggers renaming in NSTableView.

How can I let double-clicking instead trigger my own custom code (such as opening the double-clicked file)?

And also: How can I let the renaming be like in Finder, where you first single click, and then click again and quickly move the mouse pointer away? That is how renaming gets triggered in the Finder. I want it like that in NSTableView.

Comment: Have you looked at NSBrowser? It might fill your needs better since it is what Finder uses.

Comment: NSBrowser's double action and click-to-edit works the same as a table view (which is what the OP is asking about).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the documentation, NSTableView has [-setDoubleAction:](http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSTableView_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSTableView/setDoubleAction:). Clicking once to select a row, then clicking a text cell to edit behaves like the Finder by default (and neither this nor Finder have anything to do with moving the pointer quickly away - try it).

Click once to select, then click again to begin rename. Click twice (fast enough to be a double-click) and it handles the "double" action.

Comment: I would like to add little info that if you click twice on text it will go to edit mode instead of executing your custom action.

In order to execute your action and prevent from going into edit mode, cell should also be set as uneditable as @JWWalker wrote.

Comment: Xcode Table View Connections inspector has a equivalent Sent Action: "doubleAction". Control-drag from it to your controller (or into its header file to create the action method)

Comment: @PaulCollins Neat! I wonder when this was added. A long time ago I know it wasn't in IB at all.

Answer (score 2):

You must make the text cell uneditable in order for your table view to get a double-click action message.

Comment: Untrue. Growl's BeepHammer example application has both column and cell set to editable, and double-clicking works just fine in it.

Comment: I don't know about that example, but the documentation for `-[NSTableView setDoubleAction:]` says "If the double-clicked cell is editable, this message isn’t sent and the cell is edited instead."

Comment: You're right, that is what one would think judging from the documentation. But it seems the documentation is in this case erroneous. Looks like this works even if the cell is editable.